# A string with string interpolation format from database use it in C# code

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, formattablestring

For example I have a string that was retrieved from the database.

```
string a = "The quick brown {Split[0]}   {Split[1]} the lazy dog";
string b = "jumps over";
```

And then I will perform this code.

```
String[] Split= b.Split(' ');
String c= $"{a}";
Console.Writeline(c):
```

This method is not working. Do you have any idea how can this become possible? I appreciate your help. ^-^

Comment: Hello. Your question is not very clear. Can you explain little more what exactly you are expecting? What is the result you are getting from your current code?

Comment: The string interpolation syntax is a compiler thing, there is no way to invoke this at runtime. Your next best thing is to use `string.Format`, but then all the heavy lifting has to be done outside of the string.

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your response. The .Net 6 rc2 shows the value of the "string a" as it is. I mean, it doest change the "{Split[0]}" to jumps for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interpolated strings are interpreted by the compiler. I.e., for example in

```cs
string a = "fox";
string b = "jumps over";

// this line ...
string s = $"The quick brown {a} {b} the lazy dog";
```

... is converted to

```cs
string s = String.Format("The quick brown {0} {1} the lazy dog", a, b);
```

... by the compiler.

Therefore, you cannot use string interpolation at runtime with variable names in a (regular) string.

You must use `String.Format` at runtime:

```cs
string a = "The quick brown {0} {1} the lazy dog";
string b = "fox;jumps over";

string[] split = b.Split(';');
string c = String.Format(a, split[0], split[1]);
Console.Writeline(c):
```

Note that a runtime, the names of the local variables are not known. If you decompile a compiled C# programm, the decompiled code will contain generic names for local variables like `l1`, `l2` etc. (depending on the decompiler).

Comment: this is much detailed and should be the answer. +1

Comment: Thank you so much. I found what I'm looking for from your example. Here is my solution.string a = "The quick brown fox {0} {1} the lazy dog";
string b = "jumps over";

string[] split = b.Split(' ');
string c = String.Format(a, split);
Console.WriteLine(c);

Answer (score 0):

As LasseV.Karlsen and Hans Keﬆing
has explained you can use `string.Format` in this scenario. Let me give you a quick example:

```
string b = "jumps over";
string[] Split = b.Split(' ');
string c = string.Format("The quick brown fox {0} {1} the lazy dog.",Split[0], Split[1]);
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Note that this is just one example with `string.Format` while there exist countless other uses for the same. Your best resource to learn more about this method could be [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0).